# How to build this kind of Logic using arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array which consists of this set of items

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Field1"]=>
    string(8) "80000007"
    ["Field2"]=>
    string(16) "O70000006"
    ["Field3"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Field4"]=>12345
    string(0) ""
   }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Field1"]=>
    string(8) "80000008"
    ["Field2"]=>
    string(16) "O70000007"
    ["Field3"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Field4"]=>78965
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
   array(4) {
    ["Field1"]=>
    string(8) "80000009"
    ["Field2"]=>
    string(16) "H80000006"
    ["Field3"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Field4"]=>12345
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Now my question is   Iam trying to display only the items once    from array or trying to filter  the array in such a way  if the "Field2"  has
 a value starting with "O"  or "H"    and their  "Field4 "  value  should be different    . If the "Field4" value is same for the each of the row
 then we dont display that row or array item . For eaxample  from the above array  we will get 2 items as follows

> 1)80000007  O70000006  12345
>   2)80000008  O70000007   78965
>
> //we are not displaying the 3rd Item
>   because The "Field4 " is same . we
>   display only once

```
 foreach ($resultset  as $key => $value){           
            echo $key."<br>"; ///  outputs 0,1,2
            echo $value['Field2']."<br>"; // outputs O70000006, O70000007, H80000006
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to reach ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function getField2_removeDupeField4($arr){
     $f4 = array();
     $f2 = array();
     foreach($arr as $array){
          if(in_array($array['Feild4'], $f4){   continue;  }
          $firstChar = substr($array['Feild2'], 0, 1);
          if($firstChar == 'O' || $firstChar == 'H'){
               $f2[] = $array;
               $f4[] = $array['Feild4'];
          }
     }
     return $f2;
}
```

So to get the array you want:

```
$new_arr = getField2_removeDupeField4($orig_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

So... you just want some way to skip rows whose Field4 has already been printed?

Set up an array to hold all the previously printed Field4s, and check against that before printing anything. Something like this:

```
$field4s = array();
foreach ($resultset  as $key => $value){    
            $field4 = $value['Field4'];
            if (($field4[0] == 'O' || $field4[0]=='H') && !in_array($field4 , $field4s) {
                array_push($field4s, $field4);
                echo $field4;
            }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to check for the `'O'` or `'H'`